# Unit Testing SQL Query that Grabs Entire Table Contents

Tags: mysql, sql, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test a function that I use to grab the entire contents of a table in my database. However, I'm not sure on what the best way to test the query is. Normally, if I were testing a query that grabs data tied to some sort of specific ID or some other unique identifier, I would insert the data into the database and then make sure that I get the same information back.

In this case however, I already have a pool of existing data. There are several hundred records in the table and I don't want to hard code them for a comparison. I would also have to update the test every time new data gets added to the table if I did it this way. And if I didn't hard code the data, I would have to run a second query on the same data to get information for testing the result, which is very nearly like comparing the function against itself.

A potential solution I could use is to create a copy of the table I want to test at the beginning of a test script and insert a predefined-set of data into it, run the tests, and then rollback my changes. However I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about testing my function.

Is there a better way to test this kind of query?

Comment: Why not just copy the database as it is now and only use the copy for your tests only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice for testing is to have a separate *test environment* (including the content of the database) that is reliably set to a known state before each test begins. That way tests can be highly targeted, isolated from each other, and remain maintainable.

The easiest way to do this would be to have a different config for your app when it's being tested, that way you can have a different test database to connect to, for example.

Then the procedure would go like this:

1. In your test setup you would add some hard coded rows into the table (this is called a fixture).
2. In your actual test, you check that the rows returned by the function are the ones you put in your setup.
3. In your cleanup code you would delete all data from the table.

The last step returns the test database to the clean state that all tests can assume.